# How can I access an unregistered COM component in VBA?

Tags: java, vba, com

I have a COM server implemented in Java using [ComfyJ](https://www.teamdev.com/comfyj), which basically registers a custom interface using `CoRegisterClassObject`. I can access it using the following Java code:

```
OleMessageLoop.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        IUnknown unknown = new IUnknownImpl(
            COMServerSample.COMServer.CLSID,
            ClsCtx.LOCAL_SERVER);
        Automation automation = new Automation(unknown);
        automation.invoke("method2", new Object[] {new Integer(123) });
    }
});
OleMessageLoop.stop();
```

which I assume uses `CoGetClassObject` under the hood for accessing the server.

Doing that, I can access a COM server without changing the registry and without adding any metadata to the server executable.

Is there a way to access this server from VBA? Can I call `CoGetClassObject` from VBA?

Comment: What is the value of ClsCtx.LOCAL_SERVER ?

Comment: @FlorentB. the value of ClsCtx.LOCAL_SERVER is 4 (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms693716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Have your tried something like Set obj = CreateObject("new:{00000535-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}")

Comment: @FlorentB. that was the answer, thanks a lot! please post it as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an instance of a COM component by clsid, you can use CreateObject.
This example creates a new instance of the "ADODB.Recordset":

```
Set obj = CreateObject("new:{00000535-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}")
```